# find all common part between vector

Tags: algorithm, vector

I have n vectors with unique integers. I want to find all the common part between them. Is there any specific algorithm or data struct for this problem?

example:

```
std::vector<int> a = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
std::vector<int> b = {1,7,8,9,2,10,11,12};
std::vector<int> c = {4,9,8,7,0,1,2,3};
```

result:
ignore result with only one interge

7,8,9 between a and b

10,11,12 bewteen a and b

0,1,2,3 between a and c

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are looking for [Longest Common Subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

[image]

These images are calculated by a diff like program which compares lines (unordered), like shortest edit distance

- Blue lines : Deleted lines to come from left to right
- Red lines  : Changed lines
- Green lines: Inserted lines

Lines without color are unchanged = longest common subsequence. Diff result looks pretty much the same as the given results.

Reference:
A Fast Algorithm for computing longest common subsequences
by James W. Hunt and Thomas G. Szymanski
from Communications of the ACM May 1977 Volume 20 no. 5

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate as a comment, but explain your reasoning in any event.

Answer (score 0):

if you want all common subarrays with a length greater than 1, then for each element from the first array iterate over all elements in the second array if you match two elements then go to the next element in the first and second array, and so on.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
            int ii = i, jj = j, cnt = 0;
            std::vector<int> res;
            res.push_back(arr1[ii]);
            while (++ii < n and ++jj < m and arr1[ii] == arr2[jj])res.push_back(arr1[ii]);
            if (res.size() > 1) {
                for (auto x: res)std::cout << x << " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

time complexity:O(n^3)

and this another way by LCS.

```
memset(dp, 0, sizeof dp);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            dp[i][j] = 0;
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
            }
            std::cout << dp[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            if (dp[i][j] > 1) {
                for (int ii = i, jj = j, k = dp[i][j]; k; ii--, jj--, k--) {
                    std::cout << arr1[ii] << " ";
                }
                std::cout << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

O(n^3)